# ohloh CV links?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The careers site lets you link your profile with stackoverflow reputation.  But it would probably be more useful to link to an ohloh account, which lists your experience in various programming languages and contributions to projects, along with sample code.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't know what an ohloh account is?

Comment: I did a search for it. It seems to be a networking site for open source people and projects: www.ohloh.net

Comment: Sounds like I am not the only one.  I know now though.

Comment: Ohloh tracks your commits to Open Source projects and generates some objective measure of "experience" in various technologies.  It also tracks how many people claim to use particular Open Source projects.  Finally, it allows people to give "kudos" to other Open Source developers whose work they admire/appreciate.  It then combines all this information and assigns a rank to each developer on a scale of 1 (you've done pretty much nothing) to 10 (you are one of the 64 most awesome developers on the planet).

Answer (score 6):

You can certainly add as many hyperlinks as you like within the profile itself..

Comment: I think something more deeply integrated like the current github integration would be valuable.

Answer (score 5):

As Jeff mentions, you can add a link to your profile already.  You can even display one of the Ohloh-provided badges.  However, I think it might be ideal to display the badge below the StackOverflow/ServerFault/SuperUser profile links on the right as I believe they are complementary.  Having a high StackOverflow reputation shows that you can "talk the talk", a high Ohloh ranking indicates, to some extent, that you can "walk the walk".

There is an [Ohloh API](http://www.ohloh.net/api/getting_started) for retrieving information about users and projects.  That might be the basis for a more sophisticated integration, but I'm not sure what form that might take.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a site link to a third-party site instead of its own sister site?  Only if there was some kind of business deal in place, and it didn't compete with the home-grown site.

Comment: "Why would a site link to a third-party site" - dunno, ask CERN why they called it "the web"