# Github badge on careers cv

Tags: feature-request, jobs, badges

It would be great to be able to display an overview of my github account within my public cv view, to display all of my opensource projects hosted on there, perhaps with my latest commits.

For a lot of programmers their stack overflow and github accounts are the best places to show off their programming chops and to combine them together on the cv would give a great overview of their skills.

*Plus I don't feel like I have enough flair on my cv, I need at least 37 pieces.*

Comment: Why do you need a badge for this? Why don't you link to your github account/projects from your CV?

Comment: @John: Links are so 1990, Fancy (annoying) flash banners are the new thing.

Comment: @Henri: Thanks God, I'm a conservative ;)

Comment: A badge would be automatic, I don't want to have to manually update my cv every time I make a new project or fork a repo, similar to the stack overflow badges showing your current reputation.

Comment: It might be better to link to Ohloh as this can aggregate information from several project-hosting sites (GitHub, Sourceforge, Google Code, etc.).  Ohloh links have already been requested (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32473/ohloh-cv-links).

Answer (score 6):

After a year they've finally added this: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/careers-2-0-now-does-github/